# Select2 in tag mode keeps focus after close and it's not sorting in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm running select2 with tags and if I open the dropdown menu and click outside of it, it closes but the search field is still in focus. How do I completely deselect the select2 when the dropdown is closed?

Also, my tags are not added in alphabetical order in the selected area. How do I make that happen? My code:

```
var cdb_Select2Query; // This is a global object rather than one per Select2 box, since only one can be queried at a time

var defaultSorter = function(argResults) {
    return argResults.sort();
}

var prefixPreferredSorter = function(argResults) {
    if (argResults && argResults.length > 0) {
        var cdb_SearchString = cdb_Select2Query.term || '';
        cdb_SearchString = cdb_SearchString.toLowerCase(); // case-insensitive

        if (cdb_SearchString.length == 0) {
            return argResults;
        } else {
            return argResults.sort(
                function(argA, argB) {
                    var cdb_DisplayA = argA.text.toLowerCase(); // case-insensitive
                    var cdb_DisplayB = argB.text.toLowerCase(); // case-insensitive

                    if (cdb_SearchString == '') {
                        return argA.text.localeCompare(argB.text);
                    }

                    if (cdb_DisplayA.indexOf(cdb_SearchString) == 0) {
                        if (cdb_DisplayB.indexOf(cdb_SearchString) == 0) {
                            // They're both in the top group; within-group order is normal
                            return argA.text.localeCompare(argB.text);
                        } else {
                            // A goes to the top
                            return -1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (cdb_DisplayB.indexOf(cdb_SearchString) == 0) {
                            // B goes to the top
                            return 1;
                        } else {
                            // They're both in the bottom group; within-group order is normal
                            return argA.text.localeCompare(argB.text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    } else {
        return argResults;
    }
};

var cdb_Select2BaseOptions = {
    templateSelection: function(argSelection) {return $.parseHTML(argSelection.name || argSelection.text);},
    templateResult: function(argResult) {return $.parseHTML('<span data-used="' + argResult.used + '" data-custom="' + argResult.custom + '">' + (argResult.name || argResult.text) + '</span>');},
    language: {
        errorLoading: function() {return 'Results could not be loaded.';},
        inputTooLong: function(e) {var t = e.input.length - e.maximum, n = 'Please delete ' + t + (t == 1 ? ' character.' : ' characters.');},
        inputTooShort: function(e) {
            if (e.input.length == 0) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'Please enter at least ' + (e.minimum - e.input.length) + ' more ' + (e.minimum - e.input.length == 1 ? 'character.' : 'characters.');
            }
        },
        loadingMore: function() {return 'Loading more results...';},
        maximumSelected: function(e) {var t = 'You can only select ' + e.maximum + (e.maximum == 1 ? ' item.' : ' items.');},
        noResults: function() {return 'No results.';},
        searching: function(argParams) {cdb_Select2Query = argParams; return 'Loading...';}
    },
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
         return {
           q: params.term, // search term
           id: $(this).closest('.cdb-tags-menu').attr('data-c_id'),
           page: params.page
         };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
          return {
             results: response
          };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    dropdownCssClass: 'select2-inst-menu',
    dropdownParent: $(parent),
    placeholder: '-',
    tags: true,
    createTag: function(params) {
        if (params.term.trim() === '') {
            return null;
        }
        return {
            id: 'new_attribute_'+params.term,
            isNew: true,
            text: params.term
        };
    }
};

var cdb_Select2Options = $.extend({}, cdb_Select2BaseOptions, {sorter: prefixPreferredSorter});

$(target).select2(cdb_Select2Options)
.on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    cur_val = $(this).val();
})
.on('select2:select', function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
})
.on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    cur_val = $(this).val();
    $(this).one('select2:opening', function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); });
})
.on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: a demo would help to concentrate on the issue only

Comment: I tried, but it's fetching ajax data on a local server and I'm not sure how to translate that into a version that works here